# Can a JQuery be used in a layout and View in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Can the same JQuery be used in a layout and View(that uses this layout) be used with out conflicting ? Or - How can I reference to it once and both can use it ?

**File** : jquery.2.2.3.min.js

**Problem**: Layout needs it for sliding menu to work and View needs it for a calendar to work(i.e If i remove from either, either control doesnt work).

What is the best approach to this ? and what is best practices when it comes to this sort of thing ?

Below is my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>MVC | Dashboard</title>
<!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/AdminLTE/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<!-- Theme style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/AdminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
<!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
     folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/AdminLTE/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
<!-- iCheck -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/AdminLTE/plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css">
<!-- Morris chart -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/AdminLTE/plugins/morris/morris.css">
<!-- jvectormap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/AdminLTE/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
<!-- Date Picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/AdminLTE/plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
<!-- Daterange picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/AdminLTE/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/AdminLTE/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js">        </script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
</head>
 <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
-------All My HTML code to create the look - Not included this as it is a lot of code-------
<script>
 $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="/AdminLTE/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
 <!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
 <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
 <script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
 <!-- daterangepicker -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
 <!-- datepicker -->
 <script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
<script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="/AdminLTE/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<script src="/AdminLTE/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="/AdminLTE/dist/js/demo.js"></script>

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my View :

```
@model UXFrontPageTest.Models.LoginViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_Dashboard.cshtml";
}

@*<h2>Index</h2>*@

 <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
@*<div class="content-wrapper">*@
<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<section class="content-header">
    <h1>
        Calendar
        <small></small>
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="active">Calendar</li>
    </ol>
</section>
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="box box-solid">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h4 class="box-title">Draggable Events</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <!-- the events -->
                    <div id="external-events">
                        <div class="external-event bg-green">Lunch</div>
                        <div class="external-event bg-yellow">Go home</div>
                        <div class="external-event bg-aqua">Do homework</div>
                        <div class="external-event bg-light-blue">Work on UI design</div>
                        <div class="external-event bg-red">Sleep tight</div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label for="drop-remove">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-remove">
                                remove after drop
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /. box -->
            <div class="box box-solid">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Create Event</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                        <!--<button type="button" id="color-chooser-btn" class="btn btn-info btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Color <span class="caret"></span></button>-->
                        <ul class="fc-color-picker" id="color-chooser">
                            <li><a class="text-aqua" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-blue" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-light-blue" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-teal" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-yellow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-orange" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-green" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-lime" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-red" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-purple" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-fuchsia" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a class="text-navy" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /btn-group -->
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="new-event" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Event Title">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button id="add-new-event" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Add</button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /btn-group -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /input-group -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-body no-padding">
                    <!-- THE CALENDAR -->
                    <div id="calendar"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /. box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
@*</div>*@
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->
@section scripts
{
<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->

<script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="/AdminLTE/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
@*<script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js">    </script>*@
<!-- FastClick -->
@*<script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>*@
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
@*<script src="/AdminLTE/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>*@
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
@*<script src="/AdminLTE/dist/js/demo.js"></script>*@
<!-- fullCalendar 2.2.5 -->
@*<script     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>*@
<script src="/AdminLTE/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>


@*<script   src="@Url.Content("/AdminLTE/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>*@
<script>
  $(function () {
/* initialize the external events
 -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
function ini_events(ele) {
  ele.each(function () {

    // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
    // it doesn't need to have a start or end
    var eventObject = {
      title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
    };

    // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
    $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
      zIndex: 1070,
      revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
      revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });

  });
}

ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'));

/* initialize the calendar
 -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
//Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate(),
    m = date.getMonth(),
    y = date.getFullYear();
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  buttonText: {
    today: 'today',
    month: 'month',
    week: 'week',
    day: 'day'
  },
  //Random default events
  events: [
    {
      title: 'All Day Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, 1),
      backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
      borderColor: "#f56954" //red
    },
    {
      title: 'Long Event',
      start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
      end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
      backgroundColor: "#f39c12", //yellow
      borderColor: "#f39c12" //yellow
    },
    {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
      allDay: false,
      backgroundColor: "#0073b7", //Blue
      borderColor: "#0073b7" //Blue
    },
    {
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
      allDay: false,
      backgroundColor: "#00c0ef", //Info (aqua)
      borderColor: "#00c0ef" //Info (aqua)
    },
    {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
      end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
      allDay: false,
      backgroundColor: "#00a65a", //Success (green)
      borderColor: "#00a65a" //Success (green)
    },
    {
      title: 'Click for Google',
      start: new Date(y, m, 28),
      end: new Date(y, m, 29),
      url: 'http://google.com/',
      backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", //Primary (light-blue)
      borderColor: "#3c8dbc" //Primary (light-blue)
    }
  ],
  editable: true,
  droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
  drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

    // assign it the date that was reported
    copiedEventObject.start = date;
    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
    copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    copiedEventObject.borderColor = $(this).css("border-color");

    // render the event on the calendar
    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks"     (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
      // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
      $(this).remove();
    }

  }
});

/* ADDING EVENTS */
var currColor = "#3c8dbc"; //Red by default
//Color chooser button
var colorChooser = $("#color-chooser-btn");
$("#color-chooser > li > a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Save color
  currColor = $(this).css("color");
  //Add color effect to button
  $('#add-new-event').css({"background-color": currColor, "border-color": currColor});
});
$("#add-new-event").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Get value and make sure it is not null
  var val = $("#new-event").val();
  if (val.length == 0) {
    return;
  }

  //Create events
  var event = $("<div />");
  event.css({"background-color": currColor, "border-color": currColor, "color": "#fff"}).addClass("external-event");
  event.html(val);
  $('#external-events').prepend(event);

  //Add draggable funtionality
  ini_events(event);

  //Remove event from text input
  $("#new-event").val("");
});
});
</script>
}
```

Comment: What if you include the jQuery library in the layout file ? What is not working then ?

Comment: Yes of course.  You'll only run into issues if you require conflicting versions, but it doesn't sound like that's the case.

Comment: Please show your layout and view code so we can understand your problem better.

Comment: @Shyju, thanks for the reply. It is included in the layout, then the Sliding menu works. If its not in the view, then the calendar doesnt work.

Comment: How are you invoking the calendar in the view ? Share that code

Comment: Ok Ive added my Layout and View. I removed all the HTML part in the layout as its a lot of code...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just include it in the template, and it'll be available for pages rendered with that template.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both the controls (slider in layout and calendar in indidual page) needs the same version of jQuery, you may include jQuery in the layout file.

Now in your Layout, call the render section method for a section called "`scripts`" (If not already exists) and in your indidual view ,you may execute your page specific scripts inside the `scripts` section. This is to make sure that the page level scripts load after the needed libraries in layout is loaded.

So in your layout file

```
@RenderBody()
<script src="yourPathTojQueryHere"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

and in your indidual views

```
@section scripts
{
  <script src="PathToAnotherLibraryWhichRelyOnjQuery"></script>
  <script src="PathTojQueryUiWhichRelyOnjQuery"></script>
  <script>
      $(function(){
          alert("jQuery is available");

          //Now you can initialize the plugins which needs jQuery
         // Ex : $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); 

      });
  </script>
}
```

Comment: I checked and it seems I am following this approach already, but still sitting with the same problem.

Comment: What error are you getting when you follow this approach ?

Comment: Im not actually getting an error. I am using Firefox though. How can I check if there is an error ?

Comment: Check the browser console. Press F12 which will open up the dev tools and see the console tab.

Comment: 1. Empty string passed to getElementById().1 browserLink:366:13128 2. no element found1 send:1:1

Comment: Disable browserlink in Visual studio and try again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121775/discussion-between-axlewack-and-shyju).